# Error when trying to save record in ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form where a user can add different exercises to a program. This form contains two submit buttons:

1. for saving the program and assign it to another user
2. to save the program as a template, so it can be used later
   again

The **first action** worked fine before after I extended the second submit button. Sometimes it works (after clearing the cache e.g.), sometimes not and it throws an error like this:

```
activerecord.errors.models.exercise.attributes.source_id.taken
```

I have not found what .taken exactly means, but in my opinion Rails think that it must be unique? But that is not the case.

**Second submit:** when I try to save the program as a template I am getting an error

```
translation missing: de.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid
```

when I try to save the template:

```
  if params[:Template]
   @template = ProgramTemplate.new(template_params(:create))              
    if @template.save!
      flash[:success] = {'title' => I18n.t('alerts.6C.success.title'), 'text' => I18n.t('alerts.6C.success.message')}
      render :new                
    else
```

After this I checked how @template looks like with inspect where everything looks fine. When I run @template.invalid?(:name) it says true, but the .inspect shows me that the name is really stored as a String.

My **template_params**:

```
  def template_params(method = :update)
   nested_attributes = [:source_id, :series, :repetitions, :break, :sort_order]
   nested_attributes += [:id, :_destroy] if method == :update

   params.require(:program).permit(:account_id, :description, :account_patient_id, :name, :goal, :frequency, :duration, exercises_attributes: nested_attributes)
  end
```

**Model code of @template:**

```
class ProgramTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  #belongs_to :patient
  #belongs_to :program
  belongs_to :account
  #belongs_to :account_patient

  has_many :exercises, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercises, allow_destroy: true
  #has_many :program_sessions, dependent: :destroy

  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercises, reject_if: lambda { |e| e[:published].blank? }, allow_destroy: true

  validates :name, presence: true
  validate :min_no_of_exercises
```

Comment: Can you show us your `template_params` method?

Comment: See `@template.errors.messages` to find out what is wrong with the record.

Comment: `activerecord.errors.models.exercise.attributes.source_id.taken` means there is some kind of uniqueness validation on `source_id` in your model for `@template`. Can you include the model code and also any before filters and methods used inside your controller action for creating template?

Comment: @NMPennypacker edited my question

Comment: We also need the content of `Exercise`, that's probably where the validation is. Can you also post the content of `min_no_of_exercises`?